# How to call a custom sibling method of custom helper in codeigniter and use database

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, crud, grocery-crud

**EDIT**

```
<?php   defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');




 function getCrud($table_name, $subject)
{

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->database();

    $crud = new grocery_Crud();
    $crud->set_table($table_name);
    $crud->set_subject($subject);
    $crud->unset_read();
    $crud->unset_clone();
    $crud->where(array($table_name.'.flag' => '1'));

    $crud->callback_delete(function ($primary_key) use ($table_name) {
        return $CI->db->update($table_name, array('flag'=>'0'), array('id'=>$primary_key));
    });

    return $crud;
}

 function oneToMany($table_name, $subject, $rel_table,$field='name')
{

    $crud = getGrocreyCrud($table_name, $subject);
    $crud->set_relation($rel_table.'_id', $rel_table, 'name', array('flag' => '1'));
    $output = $crud->render();
    return $output;
}
```

**I can not call the above function getCrud using the ci get instance.
Are there any other methods ??**

> return $CI->db->update($table_name, array('flag'=>'0'),
>   array('id'=>$primary_key));
>   when using these line of codes in controller **($CI will be $this in controller)**  I am able to set the flag to 0 but here in helper its not happening

Comment: Are you wanting to create a Helper or a Library? Seems you are mixing up the two and are in a world of confusion. I highly recommend you go and read up on the Codeigniter user guide on how to write a helper / library.

Comment: What does it mean by you "cannot call the above function"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    class Gc_script
    {
        public $CI;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
            $this->CI->config->item('base_url');
        }

        public function getGrocreyCrud($table_name, $read=null)
        {
            $crud = new grocery_Crud();
            $crud->set_table($table_name);
            $crud->set_subject(ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $table_name)));

            $crud->callback_delete(function ($primary_key) use ($table_name) {
                return  $this->CI->db->update($table_name, array('flag'=>'0'), array('id'=>$primary_key));
            });

            return $crud;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably following should work

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


if(!function_exists('getCrud'))
{
    function getCrud($table_name, $subject)
    {
        // some code
    }
}

if(!function_exists('oneToMany'))
{
    function oneToMany()
    {
        $CI =&get_instance();

        $crud = getCrud($table_name, $subject);
        return $crud ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


    function getCrud($table_name, $subject)
    {
          // some code
    }

     function oneToMany()
    {
        $CI =&get_instance();

        $crud = $CI->getCrud($table_name, $subject);
        return $crud ;
    }
```

try this

Comment: This does not work. While that takes care of the global versus local variable issue the OP had, it still wont work as $CI-> is referring to a class method which this is NOT. The OP still has to do some reading up and make clear what they are intending to do. The getCrud function in the example is a helper function and not a class method. So it will never be called this way.

Comment: And then we have the parameter passing issue. Where is $table_name and $subject coming from?